# Why is a Promise changing behavior of getValue in RXJS?

Tags: rxjs

I had an issue where adding an extra pipe to subscription to a `BehaviorSubject` was making the wrong behavior in some tests. Whenever I did `const stores = await lastValueFrom(workingStore$);` in RXJS 7 or `const stores = await workingStore$.toPromise();` in RXJS 6, the value was not what I expected. I reduced the code down to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Dave_Stein/v7aj6bwy/

You can see on the run without a `concatMap`, `getValue` gives 3 values in an array. With `concatMap`, it will only return the first value.

The same can be observed when I use `toPromise` in this way:

```js
   console.log('here i am', bug);
   const promise = workingStore$.toPromise();
   from(events).subscribe(events$);
   const x = await promise;
   
   console.log('there i am', bug, x);
```

I get that there is an async behavior going on with `concatMap`, but I would imagine using `toPromise` would make RXJS wait for all the events being processed via subscribe to complete before resolving the promise.

In reality my `concatMap` calls a method that is async and MUST use `await` based on a library I am using.

Is there some other way to accomplish this? Order of events matters to me which is why I chose `concatMap`

Comment: I assume the issue isn't really with concatMap, rather with Promises. Promise callbacks are always executed asynchronously. I'd recommend wrapping any code that returns a Promise to instead return an Observable to ensure that your tests can pass mocks that always run synchronously. To see what I mean, change the code inside concatMap to `return of(evt);`

Comment: Good points. Not concatMap specifically. I'll update question a bit. Doesn't that imply doing `return from(Promise.resolve(evt))` would solve things? It didn't for me.

Comment: No, Promise callbacks are _always_ executed asynchronously. I'm suggesting you don't use them at all in your tests. If a library forces you to use Promises, then create code to hide this and only expose observables. Then in your tests you can provide a mock implementation that only uses synchronous observables

Comment: The solution below works with promises. I do mock the 3rd party library but make sure the mock returns promises to ensure things work as expected all the way through. Too many times I forgot `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is at: https://jsfiddle.net/Dave_Stein/nt6Lvc07/.

Rather than trying to subscribe to `workingStore$` twice, I can use `mergeWith` operator in RXJS 7. (There is another way to accomplish this in 6). Using subscribe on the same subject twice is a bad practice that can lead to issues like these apparently.

```js
const { Subject, operators, pipe, BehaviorSubject, from, lastValueFrom } = rxjs;
const { filter, scan, concatMap, mergeWith } = operators;
const run = async (bug) => {
  const events$ = new Subject();
  const historyChanges$ = new Subject();
  const workingStore$ = new BehaviorSubject({});

  const scanWorkingStoreMap = {};  
  
    events$.pipe(
      concatMap((evt => {
        return Promise.resolve(evt);
      })),
      filter((evt) => evt.name === 'history')
    ).subscribe(historyChanges$);
  
    
const newDocs$ = events$
      .pipe(
      filter((evt) => evt.name === 'new'));
      
    // historyChanges$ is a Subject
    historyChanges$
      .pipe(
      mergeWith(newDocs$),
      scan((acc, evt) => {
        const { id } = evt;
        if (!acc[id]) {
          acc[id] = [evt]
        } else {
          acc[id].push(evt)
        }
        return acc;
      }, scanWorkingStoreMap),
    )
      .subscribe(workingStore$);
      
   const events = [
     { name: 'new', id: 1},
     { name: 'history', id: 1, data: { a: 1}},
     { name: 'history', id: 1, data: { a: 2}}
   ]

   console.log('here i am', bug);
   from(events).subscribe(events$);
   
   console.log('there i am', await lastValueFrom(workingStore$));
}

run();
```